# Azure Graph API - adding user to a group works, but removing does not

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I created an API that works with Azure AD using Graph API. I have a method that adds user to a group - this one works. And I have one that removes user from a group. And this one just throws error:

```
{
  "odata.error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en",
      "value": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."
    }
  }
}
```

And I set application permissions:

- `Read and Write Directory Data` for **Windows Azure Active Directory**.
- `Read and Write Directory Data` for **Microsoft Graph**
- `Read and Write All Groups` for **Microsoft Graph**

Then I granted those permissions (in the portal). That is not enough. What else should I do to grant permission to remove user from a group?

Comment: Which Graph API are you using? Azure AD Graph or Microsoft Graph? Are those application permissions or delegated permissions? Did you acquire the token with a user context or as app-only?

Comment: If you use service principal with client credentials flow to get token, it also needs to assign directory role permissions to complete the action.

Comment: Try to use [`Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/add-azureaddirectoryrolemember?view=azureadps-2.0) powershell to assign `User Account Administrator` to your sp.

Comment: Also, What's role of the user whichi you cannot remove ? A global admin or else?